# Failed building wheel for av of OctoPrint-CrealityCloud-With-Video plugin

Tags: pi-2, arm, printing, make, plugins

i've installed the [OctoPrint-CrealityCloud-With-Video](https://github.com/crealitycloud/OctoPrint-CrealityCloud-With-Video/tree/main) package inside a RPi 2B based on octopi-1.0.0-1.9.3-20231009154319.

When i install it from the Plugin Manager i faced this issue and the plugin can't load on OctoPrint:

```
pi@octopi:~ $ ./oprint/bin/pip3 install av
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting av
  Downloading av-11.0.0.tar.gz (3.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.7/3.7 MB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: av
  Building wheel for av (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for av (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [141 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/datasets.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/deprecation.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/about.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/codec
      copying av/codec/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/codec
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/container/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/sidedata
      copying av/sidedata/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/sidedata
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/filter/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/data
      copying av/data/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/data
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      creating build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/subtitles
      copying av/subtitles/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/subtitles
      copying av/enum.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/plane.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/option.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/buffer.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/format.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/bytesource.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/utils.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/dictionary.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/packet.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/descriptor.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/frame.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/logging.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/error.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/stream.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av
      copying av/codec/codec.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/codec
      copying av/codec/context.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/codec
      copying av/codec/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/codec
      copying av/container/streams.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/container/core.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/container/output.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/container/pyio.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/container/input.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/container/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/container
      copying av/sidedata/sidedata.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/sidedata
      copying av/sidedata/motionvectors.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/sidedata
      copying av/sidedata/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/sidedata
      copying av/filter/link.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/filter/graph.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/filter/pad.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/filter/context.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/filter/filter.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/filter/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/filter
      copying av/audio/codeccontext.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/plane.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/format.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/fifo.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/resampler.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/frame.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/stream.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/audio/layout.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/audio
      copying av/data/stream.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/data
      copying av/data/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/data
      copying av/video/reformatter.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/codeccontext.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/plane.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/format.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/frame.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/stream.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/video/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/video
      copying av/subtitles/codeccontext.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/subtitles
      copying av/subtitles/subtitle.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/subtitles
      copying av/subtitles/stream.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/subtitles
      copying av/subtitles/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/subtitles
      running build_ext
      building 'av._core' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/_core.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/_core.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/_core.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/_core.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.stream' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/stream.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/stream.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/stream.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/stream.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.format' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/format.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/format.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/format.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/format.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.utils' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/utils.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/utils.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/utils.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/utils.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.logging' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/logging.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/logging.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/logging.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/logging.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.enum' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/enum.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/enum.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/enum.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/enum.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.option' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/option.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/option.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/option.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/option.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.plane' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/plane.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/plane.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/plane.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/plane.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.buffer' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/buffer.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/buffer.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/buffer.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/buffer.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.packet' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/packet.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/packet.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/packet.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/packet.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.error' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/error.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/error.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/error.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/error.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.bytesource' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/bytesource.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/bytesource.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/bytesource.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/bytesource.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.dictionary' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/dictionary.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/dictionary.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/dictionary.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/dictionary.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.descriptor' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/descriptor.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/descriptor.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/descriptor.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/descriptor.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.frame' extension
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/frame.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/frame.o
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fwrapv -O2 build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/frame.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -lavformat -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavutil -lavfilter -lswscale -lswresample -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/av/frame.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so
      building 'av.codec.codec' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/codec
      arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -ffile-prefix-map=/python3.9-3.9.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/home/pi/oprint/include -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c src/av/codec/codec.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-cpython-39/src/av/codec/codec.o
      src/av/codec/codec.c: In function ‘__pyx_pymod_exec_codec’:
      src/av/codec/codec.c:8203:48: error: ‘AV_CODEC_CAP_OTHER_THREADS’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘AV_CODEC_CAP_SLICE_THREADS’?
       8203 |   __pyx_t_8 = __Pyx_PyInt_From___pyx_anon_enum(AV_CODEC_CAP_OTHER_THREADS); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_8)) __PYX_ERR(0, 104, __pyx_L1_error)
            |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            |                                                AV_CODEC_CAP_SLICE_THREADS
      src/av/codec/codec.c:8203:48: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
      error: command '/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for av
Failed to build av
ERROR: Could not build wheels for av, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3 -> 23.3.2
[notice] To update, run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pi@octopi:~ $
```

PS: See attached log file for the complete logs: [error_logs](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmsE_DBJh7CzmgV_hbLPtZxrnqI_?e=2r9RPY)

Could anyone help me?

Thanks